# ¿Cómo corregir este error descargando un archivo usando FPDI?

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy usando FPDI pero al momento de descargar el archivo, me genera este error,

> Fatal error: Uncaught setasign \ Fpdi \ PdfParser \ CrossReference 
> CrossReferenceException: Este documento PDF probablemente usa una
> técnica de compresión que no es compatible con el analizador gratuito
> que se envía con FPDI. (Ver
> https://www.setasign.com/fpdi-pdf-parserpara más detalles) en C: 
> xampp \ htdocs \ Cosas \ Alberto_edit_pdf \ fpdi2 \ src \ PdfParser 
> CrossReference \ CrossReference.php: 251 Stack trace: # 0 C: \ xampp 
> htdocs \ Cosas \ Alberto_edit_pdf \ fpdi2 \ src \ PdfParser 
> CrossReference \ CrossReference.php (210): setasign \ Fpdi \ PdfParser
> \ CrossReference \ CrossReference-> initReaderInstance (Objeto
> (setasign \ Fpdi \ PdfParser \ Type \ PdfIndirectObject)) # 1 C: 
> xampp \ htdocs \ fdf_edit_2p \ src \ PdfParser \ CrossReference 
> CrossReference.php (68): setasign \ Fpdi \ PdfParser \ CrossReference
> \ CrossReference-> readXref (116) # 2 C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ Cosas 
> Alberto_edit_pdf \ fpdi2 \ src \ PdfParser \ PdfParser. php (158):
> setasign \ Fpdi \ PdfParser \ CrossReference \ CrossReference -> __
> construct (Object (setasign \ Fpdi \ PdfParser \ PdfParser), 0) # 3 C:
> \ xampp \ htdocs \ Cosas \ Alberto_edit_pdf \ fpdi2 \ src \ PdfParse
> in C:\ xampp \ htdocs \ Cosas \ Alberto_edit_pdf \ fpdi2 \ src 
> PdfParser \ CrossReference \ CrossReference.php en la línea 251

Como puedo cambiar la versión del PDF, ya que estoy usando FPDI que admite la versión PDF superior a 1.4?

Comment: Buen día, lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Hola! No sabemos qué código genera este error, ni sabemos a qué te refieres con cambiar la versión de un PDF. Cualquier archivo generado después de 2001 posiblemente esté en PDF v1.4 pero igual, suele haber compatibilidad hacia atrás, así que no tiene mucho sentido "actualizar el archivo". ¿Por qué no pruebas editando tu pregunta y explicando mejor cuál es el problema y qué código lo está generando? Demás que el lío está en que FPDI sí soporta la compresión que tiene, sólo que no lo ofrece en la versión gratuita... ¿cuáles son los atributos del archivo en cuestión?

Comment: Por si acaso, se edita usando el enlace [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/417204/edit) que está bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas